# android.mk include execute order

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TOP_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)/../

#Add target arm version
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
MY_PJSIP_FLAGS := $(BASE_PJSIP_FLAGS) -DPJ_HAS_FLOATING_POINT=0
else
MY_PJSIP_FLAGS := $(BASE_PJSIP_FLAGS) -DPJ_HAS_FLOATING_POINT=1
endif

# Pjsip
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjlib/build/Android.mk
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjlib-util/build/Android.mk

include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjnath/build/Android.mk
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjmedia/build/Android.mk
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjsip/build/Android.mk


#pjsip JNI
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/jni/build/Android.mk

#JSON
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/third_party/build/json/Android.mk

#GSLB
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pgslb/build/Android.mk
```

i have a android make file like this, the problem is , when start to build , the GSLB will be build first , but it depend on libpjnath.a ,witch is build by  `include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjnath/build/Android.mk` , so cause problem , i don't know why the GSLB is build when start , why ? how could i solve this problem ?

Comment: don't your GDLB makefile contains the dependency to libpjnath makefile ?

Comment: i am not fluent in makefiles, but i guess that if your main makefile contains the reference to GDLB and libpjnath, you can add the reference to libpjnath in the makefile of GDLB using the same include syntax.

Comment: i tryed, but it have no use .

Comment: If it is still relevant, publish your pgslb/build/Android.mk

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late, but I faced very similar problem with NDK and came to conclusion that order of compilation is alphabetical.